# Spring how to do the official Spring REST tutorial without using @ComponentScan?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Here's the tutorial refering to the part where it quotes

> The @ComponentScan annotation tells Spring to search recursively through the hello package and its children for classes marked directly or indirectly with Spring’s @Component annotation.

http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/#_make_the_application_executable

I don't want to make my service an application, instead, I want to deploy it in JBoss as a WAR.

How do you make Spring find your Controller without the @ComponentScan

Comment: Why do people vote down on this perfectly fine question? If you're smart enough to vote down why not just answer?

Comment: I'm going to guess it's because you don't seem to have read the documentation, which explains both how to include a specific controller without scanning and how to scan in a traditional war application.

Comment: @chrylis Well, there we go, can't you just put that in an answer and leave a link? Like how it's suppose to be?

Comment: @Louie: I think down vote is not the correct way, but the problem is that the question is missing a complete understanding of the topic. So it is really really hard to find the point where to start with an useful answer.

Comment: I feel like I have to kill my self to ask a question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start with the most strait forward question.

1) How do you make Spring find your Controller without the `@ComponentScan`

You can instantiate the Controller beans by explicite name them in the spring configuration xml

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.example.MyBean">...</bean>
```

2) I don't want to make my service an application, instead, I want to deploy it in JBoss as a WAR.

A normal Spring Web Application is a normal WAR file that can been deployed like every other (Servlet based) war file in ever Servlet container, even to JBoss.

*I think that you get confused by the term application, but I think that Spring, JBoss and you mean differentthings by an application*

**The Point is: that Component Scan is a way to find and instantiate Spring Beans (Java Objects that are maintained in a Spring Container), but this has no meaningful connection to "I don't want to make my service an application, instead, I want to deploy it in JBoss as a WAR."**